# reorganize some keys element in json subarray with JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have simple JSON and I want to reorganize the keys with JOLT transformation:
Input JSON looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "Firstname": "John",
    "LastName": "JohnLastName",
    "City": "TestCity",
    "PostCode": "25466",
    "Street": "85.",
    "HousNumber": "5",
    "Phone": "0054565685",
    "Email": "-"
  }
]
```

and wished output should be:

```json
{
  "Firstname": "John",
  "LastName": "JohnLastName",
  "Address": {
    "City": "TestCity",
    "PostCode": "25466",
    "Street": "85",
    "HousNumber": "5"
  },
  "Contact": {
    "Phone": "0054565685",
    "Email": "-"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below Jolt Spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "City": "Address.&",//Get the key and value where the key is City and place them within the Address map 
        "PostCode": "Address.&",
        "Street": "Address.&",
        "HousNumber": "Address.&",
        "Phone": "Contact.&",
        "Email": "Contact.&",
        "*": "&"// Get the remaining fields of the input JSON
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deliver the elements to the respective objects by their common properties such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*ame": "&", // accumulate names under the common node
        "Phone|Email": { // the attribute named "Phone" OR "Email"
          "@": "Contact.&" // the value brought from the upper node while determining the key "Contact" for the object
        },
        "*": {
          "@": "Address.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where *ampersand* operator replicates the value of the respective element

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]